# Cannot INSERT into generated column. Как исправить?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite

Всем привет!
Есть данная форма на сайте:
Столбец "Итог" генерируется в БД
[image: Форма на сайте]

При отправке формы, выдает ошибку, ругается на то, что не может вставить данные:

[image: Ошибка: Cannot INSERT into generated column]

Подскажите как с этим справится?

Comment: Хм, а вы сообщение об ошибке прочитали и поняли?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Не совсем понял о чем Вы. Я в это деле не спец. На работе попросили как то это исправить... Если сможете чем то помочь, то буду благодарен!

Comment: Ну так не вставляй в вычисляемое поле - делов-то...

Comment: @Akina  Так ведь там и формы нет (1 скрин) столбец "ИТОГ".

Comment: Пофиг что на форме - она только рисует. Ты смотри SQL-запрос, который вставляет либо обновляет запись.

Comment: @Akina Проверил, запрос пуст ' '.

Comment: Если бы ты еще код показал, который вызывает ошибку...

Comment: Пустая строка в качестве строки запроса ну никак не может вызвать указанную ошибку. Так что пустая строка - это результат явно неправильной попытки получить текст запроса...